# when I execute a shell script in docker container, the error is "No such file or directory"

Tags: shell, docker

My Dockerfile：

```
FROM centos:7.2
COPY gateway-deploy-1.1-SNAPSHOT /home/admin/gateway/
COPY entrypoint.sh /home/admin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /home/admin/entrypoint.sh
EXPOSE 12366
VOLUME ["/home/admin/logs"]
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "/home/admin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

When I start the container, `entrypoint.sh` should be executed, but the system prompts "No such file or directory". I tried to change the startup command to "/bin/bash" and then went to the container to see that the file exists.

Why is this problem? I have tried to make images many times, but this problem has always existed.

Comment: And did you find this file when manually strafing thrgough container?

Comment: I can find all of files I added in container

Comment: Maybe try ENTRYPOINT["/bin/bash", ... ] ?

Comment: Your Dockerfile is fine (apart from the tag centos:7.2 which isn't available (at least not for me, I had to use centos:latest). Presumably, entrypoint.sh references *another* file which cannot be found - please post the contents of entrypoint.sh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I mounted an empty directory from the host to the path /home/admin when I started the container, the file was overwritten. So this is not a problem, but my mistake.